# Plot rotated images around a pivot Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, rotation, pivot, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to plot an image that must be rotated around its corner in Python.

I could do a script that (kind of) do that job, but not around a pivot point as I wish:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PIL

picture= PIL.Image.open('images/sample-image.png')
maxsize = (40*10,30*10)
picture = picture.resize(maxsize,PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)

comp = picture.im.size[0]
larg = picture.im.size[1]

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5),dpi=300)

plt.xlim((-100,500))
plt.ylim((-100,500))
plt.imshow(picture.rotate(0,expand=True))
plt.imshow(picture.rotate(-15,expand=True))
plt.imshow(picture.rotate(-30,expand=True))
plt.imshow(picture.rotate(-45,expand=True))
plt.imshow(picture.rotate(-90,expand=True))

plt.show()
```

The result that I've got was:

[image: The result I've got]

The result I wish is:

[image: The result I wish]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `transform` keyword to define a rotation about a certain point:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
import PIL

picture = PIL.Image.open('.../Downloads/puzzle.png')
maxsize = (50*10, 50*10)
picture = picture.resize(maxsize, PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5), dpi=300)
plt.xlim((-600, 600))
plt.ylim((-600, 600))
plt.imshow(picture, transform=Affine2D().rotate_deg_around(*(0, 0), 0) + plt.gca().transData)
plt.imshow(picture, transform=Affine2D().rotate_deg_around(*(0, 0), 90) + plt.gca().transData)
plt.imshow(picture, transform=Affine2D().rotate_deg_around(*(0, 0), 180) + plt.gca().transData)
plt.imshow(picture, transform=Affine2D().rotate_deg_around(*(0, 0), 270) + plt.gca().transData)
```

[image]

[Image source](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/2113189/business_integration_interaction_productivity_puzzle_solution_icon)